# Android how to create trapezoid shape

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, layer-list

Android how to create drawable that create trapezoid shape  like this shape in the image
[image]

thank you

Comment: Try to create vector drawable and use it.

Comment: vector drawable is for icons i think, and it is for small images and i need the size(width, height) to be wrap_content not fixed size

Comment: no it for all, just set relation coordinates and Android stretch them

Comment: it will create all the white box or just transparent triangle at the top ?

Comment: It will create shape by your points

Comment: So you can create trapezoid easy

Comment: ok thank you my friend i will try it, to be honest i didn't use vector drawable before so i will search about it 
thank you again

Comment: You can create a vector drawable. please follow this https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e

Comment: @QadirHussain thank you this is what i looking for